# Integrate SanitizeFunction with React textArea onPaste

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

**Use Case:**

> I have a use case where the User can paste ONE of the following
> string(s) in `textArea` and it must be formatted to new Line:
>
> 1. Comma-space (E.g: 12, 2, 3)
> 2. Comma-newline (E.g: 12,\n2,\n3,\n)
> 3. Newline (E.g: 12\n2\n3\n)

I'm trying to use `onPaste functionality` but not sure how to Integrate this use case with React textarea `onPaste`

I have this sanitzation util that takes paste input (string) and returns an array

```
function sanatizeToArray(str){
    str=str || "";
    str = str.replaceAll(" ",""); // get rid of spaces!
    str = str.replaceAll("\n",","); // change new lines into commas
    str = str.replaceAll(",,",","); // get rid of duplicates
    return str.split(","); // break it down!
}

sanatizeToArray("12, 2, 3"); // Prints ["12", "2", "3"]
sanatizeToArray("12,\n2,\n3,\n"); // Prints ["12", "2", "3", ""]
sanatizeToArray("12\n2\n3\n"); // Prints ["12", "2", "3", ""]
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help integrate this sanitizeArray function with onPaste.

Comment: What code do you have so far for working this in to your textarea? Also why not just use `onChange`?

Comment: @JoelRummel This is the code I have so far. I need to use `onPaste` cuz the user is expected to copy paste one of these three formats:

https://codesandbox.io/s/money-input-example-forked-vsom5?file=/src/components/MoneyInputList.jsx

First one works, however second and third doesn't .. But the util seems to be working fine if i run in console individually :(

Comment: That code is working fine for me for all use cases. What exactly is your issue?

Comment: If you go to codesandbox, copy paste the second and third use case, it doesn't print correct value in a new line. (I call this sanitize function, take the results and print in new line). Thanks for all the help @JoelRummel will upvote your answer.

Comment: You could also see that there is `\n` when you copy paste the second use case in text area (which isn't expected :(  don't know whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code sample you provided in the comments, your `onPaste` integration is working fine. Your sanitize function is also working fine, depending on what exactly it is you're trying to do.

Literally typing `\n` into your textarea isn't the same as typing an actual linebreak, since `\n` automatically gets escaped to `\\n` when entered in a textarea. This means that a string like `Hello\nWorld\n!` will get processed as `Hello\\nWorld\\n!`, and your `replaceAll` call will fail to find any linebreak characters.

If you want to test pasting actual linebreaks into your input (which is the vastly more likely input), then copy-paste this block and you will notice that your code works just fine:

```
12
2
3
```

If you want to replace escaped linebreak characters as well, then you just need to add an additional `replaceAll` call:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\n", ",");
```

although I doubt that this is necessary.

Comment: You're awesome Joel!